# submenu items won't line up with parent item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down menu, however whenever I hover over a parent menu the child menu won't line up with it. I have gone through many examples and I always get the same result.

My CSS code is

```
#mainNav {
   margin-top: 20px;
   width: 800px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   padding: 0;  
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #BBFFFF;
   zoom: 1;
}

#mainNav li {
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
}
#mainNav li a {
   color: #000000;
   display: block;  
   width: 80px;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;   
   padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
   border-right: 1px solid #999;    
   zoom: 1; 
}
#mainNav li ul {
   display: none;
}
#mainNav a:hover {
   background-color: #66FF66;
}
#mainNav li:hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
}
#mainNav li:hover li {
   float: left;
   width: 80px;
   background-color: #BBFFFF;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

My HTML is

```
<div>
  <ul id="mainNav">
    <li><a href="pageone.html" id="pageOneLink">Page One</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagetwo.html" id="pageTwoLink">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagethree.html" id="pageThreeLink">Page Three</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="threePageOne.html" name="threePageOneLink>Sub Page One</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: rather than `display: block` make it `display: inline-block`

Comment: When posting code it is helpful to strip out all of the stuff that we don't need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative margin-left to pull it back in line. Add it to:

```
#mainNav li:hover ul {}
```

Or you can set padding: 0; on the same element.

Also, you are missing a closing '"' in:

```
<li><a href="threePageOne.html" name="threePageOneLink>Sub Page One</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste and try this. Something from this example will help you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mainNav{
    /*  Your mainNav decoration here */

}
#mainNav li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#0FF;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#mainNav ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding:0px;
    top:50px;
}

#mainNav li:hover ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="mainNav">
    <li><a href="pageone.html" id="pageOneLink">Page One</a>
     <br />
      <ul>
        <li><a href="onePageOne.html" name="onePageOneLin">Sub Page One</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pagetwo.html" id="pageTwoLink">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagethree.html" id="pageThreeLink">Page Three</a>
    <br />
      <ul>
        <li><a href="threePageOne.html" name="threePageOneLin">Sub Page One</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of css in there that is not specific enough and some stuff that is just in the wrong place.

I have written out a jsfiddle for you here: [A DISTILED VERSION OF YOUR CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/taxj5/)

You have list style on li instead of ul where it belongs. You are also not specific enough about the sub lists and so one. Using > like,

`.main-nav > li > a { }` will say target the first layer of li only, and in that, the only a in that li etc.

I would give the ul's classes etc. See the fiddle for what I think is the most simple approach. For the other people, please let me know if my fiddle could be more concise.

Comment: Also, for accessibility, I think a better approach would be to use a height of 0 or something instead of display: none; - that would allow the screen readers for the blind etc, to read the text even though it is not visually seen. You can actually animate the height changes too.

Comment: Here is another fiddle I forked so show the drop-down with height 0 transition instead of display none. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/SvUcL/